# pass string with white space using commandlineArgs in maven commandlineArgs plugin

Tags: maven, batch-file, mojo

Is it possible to add double quote to the **commandlineArgs** of the maven mojo plugin?

On the batch i have %1 - getting just first part of the string  until the first white space

I tried quot:  **"** but it didnt help 

e.g. `<commandlineArgs>"path"</commandlineArgs>`

I tried   **&quot ;** 
`<commandlineArgs>&quot;path&quot;</commandlineArgs>` 

But i am getting:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>export_objects</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>export_obj.bat</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>###LONG PATH WITH SPACE###</commandlineArgs>   
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XML CDATA:

```
<commandlineArgs><![CDATA[###LONG PATH WITH SPACE###]]></commandlineArgs>
```

or:

```
<arguments><argument><![CDATA[###LONG PATH WITH SPACE###]]></argument></arguments>
```

Comment: Can you shorten paths with spaces: C:\Program Files -> C:\Progra~1 or C:\Program Files (x86) -> C:\Progra~2

Comment: Another option to use <arguments> tag